# Can I speedup SSD on GigaByte H61M-S2PV

Tags: ssd

I have an old MB: Gigabyte H61M-S2PV with i3

The system is old but the processor moves good. I want to install a SSD. I took one already but I got only 190MB/s in HDTune for a SSD SATA 3 of more than 500MB/s. I installed the last BIOS version, I enabled AHCI on BIOS and installed the Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver, but it has not changed anything. Intel Rapid Storage Technology says the SATA transfer rate is 3Gb/s

What can I do to speed up? I'm also thinking about buying an adapter for PCI-Express for connecting the NVMe M.2 and change the SSD.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your motherboard only supports SATA version 2 which is limited to 3Gbps.

From [your motherboard specifications](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H61M-S2PV-rev-20/sp#sp)

> 4 x SATA 3Gb/s connectors supporting up to 4 SATA 3Gb/s devices

SATA 3Gbps means that you are limited to a theoretical maximum of 375MB/s. There are overheads that mean the actual limit is probably somewhere closer to 275MB/s. Then there is time and latency within your drive controller that might also affect things.

Depending on your CPU and memory that might further reduce things.

190MB/s is not as good as it could be but it is likely the best you will get with such an old system. At the very least an SSD will perform better than an equivalent HDD, particularly when having to do lots of seeks and file accesses. Even on SATA 3Gbps I'd prefer an SSD over an HDD, it will result in a generally more responsive system as you remove the 9.5ms seek time from every drive access.

Using the PCIe slots *might* improve things, but depending on the slot you use it may not be by a massive amount.  You have two slots:

> - 1 x PCI Express x16 slot, running at x16
>   (The PCI Express x16 slot conforms to PCI Express 3.0 standard.)
>   PCIE Gen.3 is dependent on CPU and expansion card compatibility.
> - 1 x PCI Express x1 slot
>   (The PCI Express x1 slot conforms to PCI Express 2.0 standard.)

If you are looking to use the main x16 PCIe slot then you might get a good speed as PCIe 3.0 x4 (most NVMe drives are x4) will be capable of up to 4GB/s, again dependent on your CPU. If you CPU only does PCIe 2 then you might be limited to 2GB/s.

If you have a dedicated graphics card in the x16 slot then you will have to use the x1 slot where you won't get as good a boost in speed. It is a PCIe 2 x1 slot and will be limited to at most 500MB/s which will further drop with overheads. It might be an improvement but not as big as the other slot.

Comment: I agree on the SSD vs HD, even on SATA II. I have a lot of old SATA II Macs here for legacy reasons & short of putting PCI-based drives in them which some have, there's still considerable uplift simply switching everything to SSD.

Comment: Solid State Drive (SSD) ADATA LEGEND 710, PCIe Gen3x4, M.2, 512GB can works with no BIOS modification? My PCI slots are all free.

Comment: @Caty It may work as long as you get an adapter and assuming your OS supports it, but I'm not sure if you will be able to boot from it. I think it depends on your motherboard.